# Установка PIP на Python 2

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x

Как установить PIP 7.1.2 на Python 2.7.11?

Пробовал уже способ с cmd.exe (где надо прописать python setup.py) - не помогло.

Может быть есть какой-нибудь простой способ, чтобы папку с PIP переместить куда-нибудь в папки Python?

Answer (score 2):

pip 7.1.2 включен в дистрибутив Python 2.7.11 для Windows.[image: python2.7.11]